# Resolve DNS from text file to IP address

Tags: windows, networking, command-line, dns

I am currently able to fetch an IP address from a DNS server with the 1st command shown below. However, it gets tedious typing one DNS server at a time and running command. I have tried in the past running this `for /F %i in (dns.txt); do nslookup %i; > ips.txt;` and it works. However, I am trying to apply the same concept to the below command. How can I resolve DNS address from a text file, convert IP addresses and output result in new text file?

Only works for 1 DNS to IP address

```
for /f "skip=4 usebackq tokens=2" %a in (`nslookup somedns.com`) do echo %a  > ips.txt
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the error is the `>` operator. This will actually truncate the file and then write the output to the `ips.txt` file, but you're in a loop and you're truncating the file each time. Try the `>>` operator instead.

```
for /f "skip=4 usebackq tokens=2" %a in (`nslookup somedns.com`) do echo %a >> ips.txt
```

**EDIT**: To loop over a file and get the IP address of each DNS host you'd do something like this:

```
for /f "tokens=*" %%A in (yourhostsfile.txt) do nslookup %%A >> ips.txt
```

Comment: The command works as is. What I am trying to know is a way to get the dns names from a txt file and then resolve them to IP addresses.

Comment: I edited my answer, following the same principle, it should work that way.

Comment: It shows everything, I just want the `non-authoritative` ip addresses

Comment: I'm not sure if `nslookup` admits short outputs. I know a tool that does (using the `+short` option), called `dig`. There's a Windows version, you can see how to install it this way: https://samsclass.info/40/proj/digwin.htm

Comment: Another option is to "strip" the relevant information using the `findstr` command, but in this case this seems not a good idea since you have two `Address` strings, so you wouldn't know which one is the correct one

Comment: i got a little closer with this: `for /F %i in (list.txt) do nslookup %i |findstr Address >> ips.txt` but it returns two address. I just want the non-authoritative. is there away to narrow that down to the ip?

Comment: Yep, that's what I meant in my last comment. As the first `Address` of each command execution should be the same, you can append another `findstr` command, concretely: `findstr /V ip-address`, so it matches only if it doesn't match the first IP address, so the final result would be: `for /F %i in (list.txt) do nslookup %i |findstr Address | findstr /V ip-address >> ips.txt`